# Why are HTML emails being sent by a APEX Schedulable class being delivered with blank bodies?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have an APEX class that is used to send an email out each day at 7PM:

```
global class ReportBroadcaster implements Schedulable {

    global ReportBroadcaster() {
    }

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
      send();
    }

    global void send() {
      PageReference page = new PageReference('/apex/nameofvfpage');
      page.setRedirect(true);
      Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
      email.setSubject('Example Subject');
      email.setHtmlBody(page.getContent().toString());
      email.setToAddresses(new String[]{'test@test.com'});
      Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{email});     
    }
}
```

When I execute the send() method via an instance of the ReportBroadcaster via anonymous APEX, it is delivered as expected. However, when I schedule the class, the email is delivered with a blank body. If I switch the email body to plain text, it delivers fine (but that doesn't work for me).

How do I make this work?

UPDATE:

You cannot call getContent() on PageReference instances from either scheduled APEX or @future methods (I'm not sure why that would be, but it is what it is). I think that the solution will be to create a web service that I'll call from the @future method. Seems incredibly hacky, but I'm not sure what else I could do.

FINAL UPDATE:
This is how to send HTML emails from scheduled APEX:

- Create a class that implements the Schedulable interface.
- Have the execute() method call an @future method.
- Have the @future method call a web service enabled method in the class that sends the email.

While this approach is roundabout, it works.

Comment: Out of interest, does the running user have access to the page used?

Comment: Yes. I'm running as System Admin and have access to the page.

Comment: Are you calling the webservice method using HTTP request or directly from the @future method? Can you please paste a code example?

Comment: I just tried this. Scheduled class' execute() > @future > webservice method. The PDF gets sent, but its empty.

Comment: Did anybody find a solution to this problem. I am running into the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getContent()` method is not supported in scheduled Apex. See the last line of this page:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I didn't see that. Oddly, it doesn't throw an error and actually works if the page is very small. Any idea about how to get around the issue without relying on an external system to trigger the execution?

Comment: There is a way you can do it with web services, I'm afraid I don't know the exact details but I have seen it done. It was all within salesforce but salesforce called web services on itself as though it was an external system. Heath Robinson would have been proud. Good luck and thanks, sorry I can't help more

Comment: I just implemented an approach like that and it works. I updated my question above with the approach.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of the top of my head why this doesnt work (it should), but I can maybe suggest a workaround.

You can convert your vforce page into vforce Email Template (or create a new based on the old if you are also using the page somewhere else) and then use that template as the source for your email. Key points to check in the documentation are `SingleEmailMessage.setTemplateId` in apex docs and `<messaging:*>` components in vforce docs.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same problem and was able to find Workaround. I have documented my solution here and hope it will help others.

http://www.shivasoft.in/blog/salesforce/apex/send-email-with-generated-pdf-as-attachment-from-trigger/

Regards,
Jitendra Zaa

Comment: This is not working any more. Did you find any other workarounds?